# Leaflet cluster marker spacing, or how to have smaller groups when zoomed out

Tags: r, leaflet

Making a leaflet map with clustered markers.
Is there a parameter in *markerClusterOptions()* that controls the number of groups based on the zoom level? For example, at default zoom my map shows just 3 clusters for 1800 observations. However it would be nice if there were at least twice as many clusters at default zoom.

I don't want to use *freezeAtZoom* because then users won't be able to zoom in and see each individual observation.

Data procured from: https://data.sccgov.org/Public-Safety/Crime-Reports/n9u6-aijz/data

```
library(tidyverse);library(leaflet);library(lubridate)

crime_reports <- read_csv("Crime_Reports.csv")
car_burglaries <- crime_reports %>% filter(incident_type_primary=="VEHICLE BURGLARY") %>%
  mutate(datetime=mdy_hms(incident_datetime)) %>% 
  arrange(datetime)

leaflet(car_burglaries) %>% addTiles() %>% 
  addMarkers(
    popup = ~paste(as.character(incident_datetime),",","Case number",as.character(case_number)), 
    label = ~as.character(address_1),
    clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions()
)
```

Comment: Added package and code

Comment: Thank you for doing that. It's now an excellent question. I deleted my now out-of-date comment, reversed my close vote and upvoted it. I hope it gets an answer, because my initial attempts have not been successful.

Comment: I will probably attach a good sized bounty to it even if it gets an answer first. If I were to attempt an answer now, I would probably experiment with the code at https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/showhide.html

Comment: Camille's answer looks good to me (and I'll probably award the bounty) but I'm not a regular user. What do you think?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The R `leaflet` package docs [mention](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/markers.html) that clustering is done via a plugin for the Leaflet javascript library called `Leaflet.markercluster`, documented [here](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster). Many functions in the R `leaflet` package mention that additional arguments in `...` will be passed to the underlying javascript libraries, but to use these, it's helpful to know your way around the javascript docs. For clustering, you were right to notice that `markerClusterOptions` will pass on more advanced options.

The `markercluster` docs say there's an argument `maxClusterRadius`:

> The maximum radius that a cluster will cover from the central marker (in pixels). Default 80. Decreasing will make more, smaller clusters. You can also use a function that accepts the current map zoom and returns the maximum cluster radius in pixels.

So I messed around with a couple options. Screenshots from my RStudio View pane:

The default radius of 80 pixels:

```
leaflet(car_burglaries) %>% 
  addTiles() %>% 
  addMarkers(
    popup = ~paste(as.character(incident_datetime),",","Case number",as.character(case_number)), 
    label = ~as.character(address_1),
    clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions()
  )
```

[image: default radius]

Smaller radius = more clusters:

```
leaflet(car_burglaries) %>% 
  addTiles() %>% 
  addMarkers(
    popup = ~paste(as.character(incident_datetime),",","Case number",as.character(case_number)), 
    label = ~as.character(address_1),
    clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions(maxClusterRadius = 50)
  )
```

[image: smaller radius]

Larger radius = fewer clusters:

```
leaflet(car_burglaries) %>% 
  addTiles() %>% 
  addMarkers(
    popup = ~paste(as.character(incident_datetime),",","Case number",as.character(case_number)), 
    label = ~as.character(address_1),
    clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions(maxClusterRadius = 200)
  )
```

[image: bigger radius]

If you have the default setting of showing the coverage area when hovering over a marker, it should help with figuring out the radius you want.

Worth noting that the radius is measured in pixels as the map is currently being displayed. That means that the number of clusters shown will depend on how big the map is, in pixels. If you need something more complicated, like to set the radius to scale with window size so users can resize the window while keeping the number of clusters approximately constant, you could write a function to pass that radius in as a variable, or possibly write it in javascript and pass it in somehow. I'll leave that for another post.

Comment: Thanks. Seems to address the issue. I'm only holding off on the award because I cannot reverse it and I suppose someone could propose a better answer. I had seen that function but had not understood how the cluster radius would affect the output.

Comment: @42- no problem & no need to rush. Someone else might put together a function to scale the radius based on the window size--I didn't have clear ideas about doing that

Comment: This answer was sufficient for my purposes. Thank you!

Comment: I thought I had awarded it a couple of days ago but got a warning that it was about to expire so tried to award  again.